# Fedora 11 System - Failed Hard Drive Removed, and Boot gets GRUB Hard Disk Error

Tags: linux, fedora, boot, grub, hard-drive

Greetings,

I have a machine with a 120GB ATA drive that has what I thought to be non-essential data on it. I also have a 320GB SATA hard drive with the OS/Application/Files (good data I want to keep). My 120GB ATA is failing I believe, as my computer kept slowing to a halt. However, when I move the drive from BIOS my computer will not start, says "GRUB Hard Disk Error".

I know that my Fedora system has an LVM setup. I am looking to just remove the 120GB drive from "the mix", and just have one hard drive. How do I recover ?

Thank you. I have access to a Linux Live CD right now and can make any changes. However, it won't boot into my OS - it fails.

UPDATE: here's my Grub.Conf

```
# grub.conf generated by anaconda
#
# Note that you do not have to rerun grub after making changes to this file
# NOTICE:  You have a /boot partition.  This means that
#          all kernel and initrd paths are relative to /boot/, eg.
#          root (hd1,0)
#          kernel /vmlinuz-version ro root=/dev/VolGroup00/LogVol00
#          initrd /initrd-version.img
#boot=/dev/sda1
default=0
timeout=5
splashimage=(hd1,0)/grub/splash.xpm.gz
hiddenmenu
title Fedora (2.6.30.10-105.2.23.fc11.i686.PAE)
 root (hd1,0)
 kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.30.10-105.2.23.fc11.i686.PAE ro root=/dev/VolGroup00/LogVol00 rhgb quiet
 initrd /initrd-2.6.30.10-105.2.23.fc11.i686.PAE.img
title Fedora (2.6.30.9-102.fc11.i686.PAE)
 root (hd1,0)
 kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.30.9-102.fc11.i686.PAE ro root=/dev/VolGroup00/LogVol00 rhgb quiet
 initrd /initrd-2.6.30.9-102.fc11.i686.PAE.img
title Fedora (2.6.27.24-170.2.68.fc10.i686.PAE)
 root (hd1,0)
 kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.27.24-170.2.68.fc10.i686.PAE ro root=/dev/VolGroup00/LogVol00 rhgb quiet
 initrd /initrd-2.6.27.24-170.2.68.fc10.i686.PAE.img
title Fedora (2.6.27.24-170.2.68.fc10.i686)
 root (hd1,0)
 kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.27.24-170.2.68.fc10.i686 ro root=/dev/VolGroup00/LogVol00 rhgb quiet
 initrd /initrd-2.6.27.24-170.2.68.fc10.i686.img
title Fedora (2.6.27.21-170.2.56.fc10.i686)
 root (hd1,0)
 kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.27.21-170.2.56.fc10.i686 ro root=/dev/VolGroup00/LogVol00 rhgb quiet
 initrd /initrd-2.6.27.21-170.2.56.fc10.i686.img
title Fedora (2.6.27.19-170.2.35.fc10.i686)
 root (hd1,0)
 kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.27.19-170.2.35.fc10.i686 ro root=/dev/VolGroup00/LogVol00 rhgb quiet
 initrd /initrd-2.6.27.19-170.2.35.fc10.i686.img
title Upgrade to Fedora 10 (Cambridge)
 kernel /upgrade/vmlinuz preupgrade repo=hd::/var/cache/yum/preupgrade stage2=http://chi-10g-1-mirror.fastsoft.net/pub/linux/fedora/linux/releases/10/Fedora/i386/os/images/install.img ks=hd:UUID=f11769ba-29bc-46de-8c40-a949720a438e:/upgrade/ks.cfg
 initrd /upgrade/initrd.img
title Win
 rootnoverify (hd0,0)
 chainloader +1
```

Answer (score 0):

i would try this:

- remove the bad drive
- boot livecd
- reinstall grub

  grub-install --root-directory=/media/your/harddrive /dev/yourhdd

Comment: Did that, got these results. (rebooting now)

[liveuser@localhost boot]$ su
[root@localhost boot]# grub-install --root-directory=/media /dev/sda1
Installation finished. No error reported.
This is the contents of the device map /media/boot/grub/device.map.
Check if this is correct or not. If any of the lines is incorrect,
fix it and re-run the script `grub-install'.

# this device map was generated by anaconda
(hd0)     /dev/hda
(hd1)     /dev/sda

Comment: It appears to have changed something, but when it attempts to boot my computer just Beeps and reboots without any user input - an infinite loop. What now?

Comment: probably your bad hdd play a certain role in your installation.
try put back the bad hdd and after success boot, paste the mount output and see where the bad hdd is mounted as